# $\sigma$-algebra of a $\sigma$-algebra: $\sigma(\sigma(\mathbb{R}))$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, borel-sets

Let $\sigma(\cdot)$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra of its input. So $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of real numbers.

**Question:** I am wondering whether $\sigma(\sigma(\mathbb{R}))$ is equal to $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$, or it is different. (If the analysis is simpler, I am only wondering Borel $\sigma$-algebras.)

**More explanation:** The reason for my confusion is the following: $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$ is already closed under complements, countable unions, and countable intersections. So $\sigma(\sigma(\mathbb{R}))$ should be equal to $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$. However, the reason I do not fully agree with this statement is that $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$ is a set of intervals, hence $\sigma(\sigma(\mathbb{R}))$ should be a set of sets. I think $\sigma(\sigma(\mathbb{R}))$ is the powerset of $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$, but I have never heard of a powerset of an uncountable set.

Edit: Thanks to the amazing comments, this question is now resolved.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142026/discussion-on-question-by-independentvariable-sigma-algebra-of-a-sigma-alg).

Answer (score 1):

The power set of $X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. After all, it's closed under all the required operations. And, you can have power sets of uncountable sets just fine.

This is true for both $\mathbb{R}$ and  $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$.

But, it's probably not the only one on $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$.

Your intuition that it can't be the same thing as $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$ because it should be composed of sets of sets is correct.

I don't know what a smaller algebra over  $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$ would be.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was thinking exactly what you said. But the comments on my post kind of contradict this answer. I think, however, the recent comment of @Mariano to 
@ snoop is in line with this confusion :)

Comment: I think those comments are making a point about notation. They may have a valid point about how you are using $\sigma$; eg the comment about the meaning of $\sigma(A)$ in the context of $A\subset X$